How can I see all the SharePoint Sites a user is an owner of with Microsoft Graph?
I'm trying to get as a response preview on Microsoft Graph all the SharePoint sites a user is a part of, using a "get" querie but haven't got anywhere
I've tried with my user and other users, with their ID, name, username and email, the best result I got was with the ID but it wasn't even close of what I needed.
This is the code that most helped me so far:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/microsoft.graph.getAllSites()
And I was trying to find a way to insert into the parentesis a way to identify the user, but I'm starting to think this is not what that parameter is for.
So all I need is to just get, through an user ID, name, username or anything that'd identify the user, all the SharePoint Sites this user is an owner of.

To see all the SharePoint sites a user is an owner of with Microsoft Graph, you can use the following query:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=owners:{userPrincipalName}

